# Ignore specific files when pulling from forked upstream origin

Tags: git, pull

In git, how do you exempt certain files when pulling from an upstream origin (i.e. the original project)?

I have a project that I'm working on that was originally forked from a repository that is very active. I've added the original as a remote named "upstream" so that it's possible to run:

```
git pull upstream
```

and update the project to the most recent commit.

*The problem:* there are some files (e.g. my `Gruntfile.js`) that I do not want to update alongside the original project. Whenever I pulled these commits, I would get merge conflicts because I've changed the files in my own version.

I do want to track these files for my own local commits and pull changes from my own origin, so adding these to `.gitignore` permanently isn't an option.

My current solution is to have a grunt task temporarily add `Gruntfile.js` and others to `.gitignore`, pull from upstream, and then remove them from `.gitignore` so that I can track my own changes and push to my origin. However, this feels hacky.

Is there any way I can ignore these files only when pulling from "upstream"?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes you can do that.

> **git pull is shorthand for git fetch followed by git merge FETCH_HEAD**

So first you can do a,

```
git fetch upstream
```

followed by,

```
git merge --no-log --no-ff --no-commit upstream/branch
```

Git will stop before committing. So, you should be able to modify the merge, and exclude the required files.

**UPDATE**

The commands can be combined using git alias.

Create an alias inside ~/.gitconfig

```
[alias]
   fnm = !git fetch upstream && git merge --no-log --no-ff --no-commit upstream/branch
```

You can further add,

```
[alias]
   fnm = !git fetch upstream && git merge --no-log --no-ff --no-commit upstream/branch && git reset file/path/not/to/be/updated && git checkout file/path/not/to/be/updated
```

Use `git fnm` for the complete operation.

Comment: Thanks, that makes sense. Is there a way to configure this in something like a gitignore file or is using a task runner like grunt/gulp the best way to go about doing this? fetching/merging in the command line isn't a huge burden, but if there's a way to configure this that's the preferable option.

Comment: @weems you can use aliases.

Answer (score -2):

> However, this feels hacky

A less hacky way could be to avoid keeping a forked version of the file while wanting its updates. I don't know what your changes are, but what about proposing a merge request with your modifications?

If your modifications are rather personal (eg: local urls), what about proposing a merge request where you introduce a local configuration file?

That's what is done for example with https://github.com/fabelier/Doorbell: it provides a [config.js.template](https://github.com/fabelier/Doorbell/blob/master/config.js.template) file which is used by default, but the users can provide a `config.js` file to add their own specificities ; and this file isn't kept in Git.