# git: many local changes that I don't want to commit

Tags: git

The problem:

I cloned a repository, there are some configuration files to customize the behaviour of the compiled app, I changed some of them (about 10) to suit my needs. Now, every time I commit something, I have to go through line by line in the output of `git status` (or "unstaged files" in my daily used GUI), and that 10 files, which I don't want to commit, are always there, this quickly becomes annoying.

Is there some unknown (to me) feature of git or trick to let git ignore these 10 files when I need `git status`, but when I `git pull` the changed (by upstream) version of these files, I still get a conflict (if there is one)?

I cannot merge all these files into one big config, partly because they are different things and partly because the app is running in production for some times now.

Git aliases probably won't work, for if nothing fancy needs to be done, I usually use a GUI, (better looking diff, convenient control of what to commit, etc.), not `git` in a terminal.

Comment: do you want that changes with you or not if not then use git stash

Comment: If you use the terminal, git alias could work. `[alias] st = !git status -s | grep -v -E 'path1_to _ignore|path2_to_ignore'`.

Comment: @PardeepPathania I want to keep the changes, because compilation depends on them, stash is a PIA, I cannot use it to stash some individual files (`-p` is not easy to use)

Comment: The better solution (if you are able to do it) is probably to make sure that you are not in this situation. Try to make the configuration so that no files included in the repo need be changed when configuring. E.g., by allowing users to create their own config file that will also be included in the compilation process.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `.gitignore` file and add paths to these 10 files there.

If for some reason you don't want to use `.gitignore`, you may try `.git/info/exclude` - it works like `.gitignore`, but is not shown in git status, as it is in `.git` folder.

Comment: .gitignore has no effect on **unstaged files**. It only applies to **untracked files**.

Answer (score 1):

One trick works as follows:

you might try: checkout a new branch

```
git checkout -b mybranch
```

commit changes to these files

```
git add <config-files>
git commit -m "my safe of config files"
```

check whether there are unsafed chagnges:

```
git status
```

Now, if you do the following

```
git pull origin master
```

you get all remote changes, AND conflicts for the config files (if any)

Whenever you want to push your changes, you will NOT want to push changes to the config files

```
git checkout master
git cherry-pick mybranch
```

And choose what you want/don't want to push

Comment: guess this is the best I can get, maybe I should write a `prepare_to_commit.sh` and a post commit hooks

Answer (score 0):

You can set this alias and ignore your configuration files whenever you want to update your branch with the remote,

```
[alias]
   fnm = !git fetch upstream && git merge --no-log --no-ff --no-commit upstream/branch && git reset file/path/not/to/be/updated && git checkout file/path/not/to/be/updated
```

More explanation [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25315991/1587370)